# Responsive table issues when going responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So I'm trying to use this here:

http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Geprd

Now it works partially.

At the moment, If you use the demo you can see the `th's` is pushed to the left.

This is a slight issue for me as I have multiple things that could change with this.

At the moment, MY table is populated by jQuery. The table rows takes around 2-3 seconds to load.

The issue is, If there's nothing inside the response I have this `Nothing found` spanning across 6 columns. The JavaScript tries to add the column headers inside when I really need this to be ignored.

It also doesn't seem to show the table headers when there actually is information in the table.

I do get an error in my console which is this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'rows' of null
```

Which is on this line here:

```
for (var i = 0, row; row = tablebody.rows[i]; i++) {
```

Now I've had to change form ID's to classes as I already use the ID elsewhere. Just if this makes a massive difference.

Thanks,

Sam

Comment: Can you also provide a snippet of the cases where **'It also doesn't seem to show the table headers when there actually is information in the table'**,  as for the error its always best to have a check `if(tablebody && tablebody.rows)` . the reason could be some event issue ( timing of events ?) are you using any events ?

Comment: @ManuAntony So how are you wanting to see this? are you wanting code? or image?

Comment: code and image , would be helpfull

Comment: If you look at the codepen its basically the same, However more headers to columns.